# Serialization operation failed due to unsupported type Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageState

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, brokeredmessage

I have a C# app which subscribes to the Azure Service Bus Queue and listens to the messages from the Queue using `BrokeredMessage`. This app receives the message, executes its business logic and finally when it try to complete the msg ( `msg.CompleteAsync()`, `msgSender.SendAsync(msg.Clone())`) i.e. remove message from the Queue and move it to the Audit Queue, then I get an exception - `"Serialization operation failed due to unsupported type Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageState"`

Can anybody help how to get override of it?

```
Stack Trace -
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SerializationUtilities.ConvertNativeValueToByteArray(Int32 messageVersion, PropertyValueType propertyTypeId, Object value)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage.SerializePropertiesAsBinary(BrokeredMessage message, XmlWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageEncoder.WriteHeader(XmlWriter writer, BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage, SerializationTarget serializationTarget)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage.WriteHeader(XmlWriter writer, SerializationTarget serializationTarget)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage.System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteIXmlSerializable(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlSerializableWriter xmlSerializableWriter)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteIXmlSerializable(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at WritemessagesToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , CollectionDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at WriteSendToXml(XmlWriterDelegator , Object , XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext , ClassDataContract )
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.WriteDataContractValue(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, Object graph)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.XmlObjectSerializerBodyWriter.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BodyWriterMessage.OnWriteBodyContents(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessageWriter.WriteMessage(Message message, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 initialOffset, Int32 maxSizeQuota)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BinaryMessageEncoderFactory.BinaryMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.EncodeMessage(Message message)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendAsyncResult.WriteCore()
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendAsyncResult..ctor(FramingDuplexSessionChannel channel, Message message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnBeginSend(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Channels.OutputChannel.BeginSend(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.SocketConnectionChannelFactory`1.DuplexSessionChannel.BeginSend(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.DuplexCorrelationAsyncResult..ctor(DuplexRequestSessionChannel parent, Message wcfRequest, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
```

Comment: Tamas - Can you include the logic that you use to place a message on the audit queue? Also can you include an example message?

Comment: Logic to send msg in Audit Queue: 
MessageSender msgSender = await messageFactory.CreateMessageSenderAsync("ops/audit", QueueName);
msgSender.SendAsync(msg.Clone());

Comment: and the app receives the message of type BrokeredMessage, which has certain properties and the msg body looks like below.
{
  "RootNode": {
    "ChildNode": [
      {
        "Timestamp": "5/6/2013 6:35:05 PM",
        "Status": "Status",
        "Id": "0",
        "Identifier": "INDXYZ",
        "CandidateId": "1000",
        "BatchId": "59bf64aa-3ccc-4252-a8fd-dc5fbe0e2b9d"
      }    
    ]
  }
}

Comment: What does the code look like that sets the body of the message?